# UDT in VBScript: "Error: Expected identifier"

Tags: vbscript, user-defined-types

I'm used to ClassicVB/VB.Net but not VBScript, and I'm getting an error when calling the script below from an application:

```
# $language = "VBScript"
# $interface = "1.0"

'Microsoft VBScript compilation error
'Error: Expected identifier
Public Type MyType
    Caption As String
    Dir As String
End Type

Sub Main
    'Whatever
End Sub
```

I've googled for samples, but didn't find what's wrong with the above.

Thank you.

---

Edit: Problem solved by using a hash/dictionary instead:

```
Set hash = CreateObject ("Scripting.Dictionary")

hash.add "MyDir", "cd /usr/src/mydir"
hash.add "Linux", "cd /usr/src/linux"

keys = hash.Keys
for index = 0 to hash.Count - 1
    Set tab = crt.session.ConnectInTab("/s 192.168.0.3")
    tab.Caption = Keys(index)
    Set tabscreen = tab.Screen
    tabscreen.Send hash.item(Keys(index)) & vbcr
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [no user-defined structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30593abb%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in vbscript.

There are [user-defined classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ah5852c%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), however.